# Incompatible types when using fragmentManager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Good day,

Im trying to figure out how I can communicate between two fragments. I followed the android way (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) but I find that this way, the 2 fragments are too tightly coupled to each other.

I found another way that might be better, I am following the below video [Android Fragment Communication](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvG20PAUdcU) and at 3:40 he references Fragment2 using fragment manager (Code is below for ease of use)

```
    @Override
public void responde(String data){
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentB f2 = (FragmentB)manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
}
```

all this works fine for him. The minute I try i get an error (Incompatible types) even though my "FragmentB" is a fragment and basically identical.

Comment: use `getSupportFragmentManager` instead of `getFragmentManager();`

Comment: Thanks that worked 100%